Prove the distribution in Coupon Collecting is geometric distribution
Question:Fix $n\in \mathbb N$,let $(X_k^{})_{k\geq1}$ be a sequence of independent random variables uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.
Let $N_m$ be the number of distinct values in the finite sequence $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_m$,and set $$\tau_k^{}(\omega):=\inf\{m\geq1:N_m^{}(\omega)=k\}$$My textbook ask me to show that $\tau_k^{}-\tau_{k-1}^{}-1,k\in \{2..n\}$ is geometric of parameter $(k-1)/n$,
i.e.$$m_{k-1}\in \mathbb N,\mathbb P(\tau_k^{}-\tau_{k-1}^{}-1=m_{k-1})=\big(\frac{k-1}{n}\big)^{m_{k-1}}(1-\frac{k-1}{n})$$
Here is my attempt:
Take $k=2$,and consider the set:$$\{\omega\in \Omega:\tau_2(\omega)-\tau_{1}^{}(\omega)=m_{1}+1\}$$I try to find an equivalent form:$$\{\omega:\tau_2-\tau_{1}^{}=m_{1}+1\}=\{\omega:X_1=..=X_{\tau_2-1},X_{\tau_2}\neq X_1\}$$and by independence of $(X_k)_{k\ge 1}$ we get:$$\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X_1=..=X_{\tau_2-1},X_{\tau_2}\neq  X_1)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{P}(X_1=..=X_{\tau_2-1}=k,X\neq k)\\=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n^{\tau_2-1}}(1-\frac1n)
=\frac1{n^{\tau_2-2}}(1-\frac1n)\end{align}$$Since $\tau_2-\tau_1-1=\tau_2-2=m_1$,the case when $k=1$ is done.
But when $k\ge 1$,i find it hard to get such an equivalent form of the set $\{\omega:\tau_k-\tau_{k-1}^{}=m_{k-1}+1\}$.
I think it should be some kind of Combinatorics,but i can't describe it clearly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Think of picking a ball out of a bag containing $n$ distinct numbered balls uniformly with replacement.
First see that $\tau_{1}=1$. You pick up the first ball and note the number it bears. How many tries do you need before you pick up a ball which has a different number from the first ball you picked up? The success probability is $\frac{n-1}{n}$ and the failure probability is $\frac{1}{n}$.
So $P(\tau_{2}-2=i)=(\frac{1}{n})^{i}\frac{n-1}{n}\qquad i=0,1,....$
Similarly, suppose that you haved picked enough balls to get $k-1$ distinct balls. i.e. suppose $\tau_{k-1}=m_{0}$ (say). Then how many more balls do you need to pick before you get the $k$-th distinct ball? Again, the success probability (getting a ball different from the $k-1$ types you have been picking up) is just $\frac{n-k+1}{n}$ and the failure probability is $\frac{k-1}{n}$.
So $P(\tau_{k}-\tau_{k-1}-1=i|\tau_{k-1}=m_{0})=(\frac{k-1}{n})^{i}\frac{n-k+1}{n}\qquad i=0,1,2,...$
As the RHS is independent of $m_{0}$, we have $$P(\tau_{k}-\tau_{k-1}-1=i)=(\frac{k-1}{n})^{i}\frac{n-k+1}{n}\qquad i=0,1,2,...$$
For more on why this toy example is useful, see Negative Binomial Distribution
